# Getting height of scaled image

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm getting original sizes of an image. There is css applied to an image via `max-width:473px;` and height is resized automatically by the browser. But inside image `load event` i'm getting original, non-scaled sizes.

So basically original image sizes were `506x337` and after css rule image becomes `473x315`. How do i get `315px` height inside `load event`?

*Update*

There is the snippet for testing:
http://jsfiddle.net/CXNan/

Comment: Show us the code you are using ?

Comment: Tried this? `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("idOfYourImage"), null).getPropertyValue("height")`

Comment: Aha! Pardon, actually it's working. I have moved that check right inside load. So it seems some abstraction layer is messing something with the image.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Updated the main post with the example code.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks, just did. Added a possible workaround I found for IE also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use

```
this.offsetHeight
```

see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXNan/3/). It contains read-only pixel size, see [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetHeight). It is supported in MSIE and should be cross-browser reliable.

Comment: Woah indeed. How did i missed it... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the computed height of your element as I posted in the comment @ Question.

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("idOfYourImage"), null).getPropertyValue("height")
```

As you guys already noted, isn't cross-browser (a.k.a. not IE or old stuff).

---

**Update**

I've found this [getComputedStyle for IE](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/) but couldn't test it yet. **Might** be okay because as http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/getComputedStyle/ says, the older IE API was called `currentStyle`, which this "getComputedStyle for IE" uses.

The only problem for the currentStyle is that `getComputedStyle` will always return a pixel value if possible while `currentStyle` returns the raw value (so `width:50%` on css will return 50%, not the pixel size of 50% of the parent).

Answer (score 0):

Divide the max width by the aspect ratio and you will get the scaled height. Note that if the image is less than the max width, no scaling will be done. Something like this:

```
var height = img.width > 473 ? 473 / (img.width/img.height) : img.height;
```

Comment: I'm developing slider, it will not know what max-width is set out there on another website for example.

Comment: .. How would you write JavaScript that runs on another website?

Comment: If you use `new Image` it will automatically add `width` and `height` attributes. Try using `document.createElement('img')` instead.