# CSS3 how to calculate height and width after scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit-transform

Is there any jQuery solution that to find exact display height of the `-webkit-transform: scale(0.7851);`

the `scale` value may vary that is why looking for proper solution

Tested these options unfortunately didn't find solution yet :(

```
height()
innerHeight()
outerHeight()
outerHeight(true)
```

I think this issue only can fix one the basis of mathematics ;)

Comment: Once the animation had over, take the height() and width of the element.

Comment: @EinerS thanks for your suggestion testing that way

Comment: It seems the `height()` and `width()` methods don't (yet) take CSS transformations into account. [It's a known issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11114). I think the best solution is to scale the image in jQuery instead of in CSS, if you need jQuery to compute the end result. Otherwise, parse the `-webkit-transform` value and extract the scaling factor yourself.

Comment: Test these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405397/getting-height-of-scaled-image after the animation has ended.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect).

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zYLEL/2/).